# Question in defining a tensor

Tags: tensors

I am confused with definition of tensor.
Some texts give definition of tensor as

$n$th order tensor is a mapping
$$
T: \mathbb {R^{n_d} \times \dots \times R^{n_d} \rightarrow R}$$

$ \mathbb {R^{n_d}}$ is real $n$dimensional space. We can make this definition for a special case, such as second order tensor.

I understand from this definition that tensor produces a real number. Is that a scalar (zero order tensor)?

On the other hand, some texts define a (second order) tensor as 
$$c_i = A_{mi}e_m$$

$A$ is second order and $c,e$ are first order tensors.

In this case, a second order tensor produces first order tensor.

So, what exactly a tensor gives out as a result - a first or second order tensor? Or am I making some mistake in understanding the definition? Can someone comment?

Comment: See these questions: [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1775855/representing-a-linear-transformation-as-a-tensor), [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1108842/why-is-a-linear-transformation-a-1-1-tensor), [3](https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/why-is-a-linear-transformation-a-type-1-1-tensor.558822/) (or more specifically, their answers).